# Default constructor of test fixture cannot be referenced

Tags: c++, unit-testing, visual-studio-2015, googletest, default-constructor

I am having issues compiling a file with a test fixture using Google Test in Visual Studio 2015. The class I am attempting to create the test fixture for is named **Counter**.

The counter class under test has a protected, default constructor that initializes various protected member variables. These member variables in the **Counter** class include objects, pointers to const objects, ints, and doubles.

The **DefaultConstructor** test fails to compile with the following error message `the default constructor of "CounterTest" cannot be referenced -- it is a deleted function`.

To be clear, I am trying to instantiate a Counter object (using it's default constructor) in the CounterTest class (test fixture) to use across individual tests.

```
// Counter.h
class Counter : public ConfigurationItem {
protected:
    EventId startEventIdIn_;
    int numStarts_;
    CounterConfigurationItem_Step const* currentStep_;
    double startEncoderPosMm_;
private: 
    FRIEND_TEST(CounterTest, DefaultConstructor);
};

// GTest_Counter.cpp
class CounterTest : public ::testing::Test {
protected:
    Counter counter;
};

TEST_F(CounterTest, DefaultConstructor)
{
    ASSERT_EQ(0, counter.numStarts_);
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Is it even possible to let a test fixture be friends with a class being tested for protected/private member access? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: declare CounterTest as friend class.

```
class Counter : public ConfigurationItem {
protected:
    EventId startEventIdIn_;
    int numStarts_;
    CounterConfigurationItem_Step const* currentStep_;
    double startEncoderPosMm_;
private: 
    friend class CounterTest;
    FRIEND_TEST(CounterTest, DefaultConstructor);
```

};

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you did not post the complete definition of class `CounterTest` since the code you've posted compiles without errors if I add a dummy `Counter` class:

```
class Counter
{
public:
    int numStarts_;
};
```

Since the error message suggests that there is no default constructor for class`CounterTest`, I am guessing that you added a non-default constructor to the class. In C++, this means that the default constructor will be removed if you do not specify one explicitly. This is an issue because googletest instantiates test fixture classes using only a default constructor, you cannot use a non-default one to instantiate a test fixture. If you need to perform some different actions before each test, you can add version of `SetUp` method with parameters to the fixture class and call it with desired input arguments at the beginning of each test.

Comment: I have not added a non-default constructor to the **CounterTest** class. I have not left anything out of the **CounterTest** class shown above, it is exactly how it is in my actual code. I have added some additional interface details to the Counter class since your comment as well.